# How do i force System Activity to portrait mode in android?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, portrait

I am starting wifi settings like this

**startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));**

but i want to make this resulted activity to be fixed portrait mode.

how can i do that?

Comment: basically you can't

Comment: then how to do that ? any alternatives..@Selvin

Comment: Why android is not allow this ..any technical reason @Selvin

Comment: Yes, obviously this activity belongs to another application

Answer (score -1):

Use this line in **Activity**.

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: Sorry use this.in activity: 
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);